# how could add literal string in vim snippet?

Tags: string, vim, code-snippets

I wanna write a snippet like this:

````
snippet code
    ``` ${1:ruby}

    ```
````

but  ``` `` ``` is used to wrap script command, how could I make it?

Thanks all !

Comment: please tell me you tried escaping them with \ first

Comment: @AndyRay  yes, I tried it, doesn't work , so I asked it here!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have mentioned which snippet plugin you're using. I'm assuming the original snipMate, because that one doesn't handle escaped backticks.

You can work around this with a Vim expression which yields the backtick:

```
snippet backtick
    `!v nr2char(96)`
```

In your case, I would use

```
snippet code
    `!v repeat(nr2char(96),3)` ${1:ruby}

    `!v repeat(nr2char(96),3)`
```

Comment: Thanks first, yes, I use snipMate plugin, I have tested the `repeat(nr2char(96),3)` in vim, my code is `:echo repeat(nr2char(96),3)`, it worked

but When I added your code in my markdown.snippets without the echo,and adjust indents, it comes out `invalid expression`

Comment: Oh, sorry; I'm using a personal fork, this might not work in the original plugin. I've done some more research; see my other answer.

Comment: @user2031771: My answer was for the original snipMate, the `!v` added by your edit presumably is extended UltiSnips syntax, right?! I don't mind the edit; users should figure this out, and probably UltiSnips is more commonplace by now.

Comment: If you are using ultisnips you also need `endsnippet` at the end of snippet

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of snipMate allow for escaping backticks:

```
snippet code
    \`\`\` ${1:ruby}

    \`\`\`
```

https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate

https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim

Answer (score 0):

The original snipMate as found on [vim.org in version 0.83](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) doesn't allow escaping of backticks. However, [version 0.84 in the abandoned repository](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) seems to have it (cp. commit b2937829). It might be worth a try.

Alternatively, I have separately added that enhancement to my [personal fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/snipmate.vim); unfortunately, it's mixed in there with many customizations and stuff that will not suit you. (But you could theoretically extract a patch from the list of commits.)

Maybe it's best to move to another, more modern and maintained snippet plugin. [UltiSnips - The ultimate snippet solution for python enabled Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) is currently en vogue (but requires Python support).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have python env, and I will try UltiSnips